# How do I get the previous HTML text prior to a node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

UPDATE:
Someone asked: *for what purpose would I want to do this?*
I'm trying to get the string index of a selected node server side, and since I have to account for repetition of small selections / nodes, I figure getting all html prior to the selected node on the client side would help in being the most accurate way to get the index.

lets say I have html like this:

```
<tag>
   <child>
      <subchild>
      </subchild>
   </child>
</tag>
```

and I "select" subchild.
I want to get all preceeding HTML as text** prior to that node.. so, in this case that would be:

```
<tag>
   <child>
```

is there a slick, easy way to do that?

** I specify "as text" because, using jQuery / modern browsers, incomplete tags would become valid, as jQuery tries to make sure things don't break. Since I would not doing DOM manipulation with this information, I don't need valid HTML syntax.

Comment: For what purpose? JavaScript isn't designed to grab fragments of HTML code since it only knows what the browser has rendered, not what is in the original source code.

Comment: It's not jQuery that "fixes" the markup, it's the browser (assuming the HTML is coming from the DOM).

Comment: Ignoring that for the moment, you haven't specified how far back you want your HTML fragment to begin. Do you want to start at a particular tag? The body? or the original HTML tag?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get the string index of a selected node server side, and since I have to account for repetition of small selections / nodes, I figure getting all html prior to the selected node would be the most accurate way to get the index.

Comment: If you want to manipulate the code server-side, then client-side JavaScript/jQuery isn't what you want. Again, what the source code says and what jQuery reads may be completely different things. At the very least, the whitespace will change completely. You won't get the same index from both places.

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks for asking, I should have clarified that. I only want it to go back to a specific element with an ID. Kind of like how some Xpath path finders only goes back until it hits an element with an ID. (this means the ID MUST be unique.. but I shouldn't have a problem with that) =D

Comment: @Blazemonger well, I'm trying to find indices based on a user's selection, so, I need both. jQuery / js to get approximate location, and the server verifies.

Comment: Any solution we give you will probably not do what you want.  Sorry. You should probably back up and think about how to handle this entirely client-side or entirely server-side.

Comment: this can't be done fully on the server side. cause, lets say, there are multiple child tags, how does the server know which one the user selected?

Comment: Users don't select tags -- they select DOM elements or check boxes or click buttons. When that happens, you take `name` and `value` or other attributes and submit it to the server for processing. I can't help you more than that without a clear picture of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ids or data-attributes to keep track of what the user has selected? That way you could be sure the server and the client refer to the same elements.

Comment: @Blazemonger you're right, they don't select tags, I suppose I should have said: I've created a script that returns the DOM element containing a user's text selection, and that is what I need to find the index of. =\

Comment: @Juhana do you have an example, one that possibly deals with repeated elements? I'm the only one working on this project which is terrible for creativity. =(

Comment: `<div data-index="5">...</div>`, then `$( this ).data( "index" )`

Comment: @Juhana oh. That is a simple solution, but I'm not allowed to edit the user's content stored on the server for legal reasons. So, the index has to be found with js.